# wordpress get value of var_dump

Tags: wordpress

Hi i try to get a variable value of wc_orders in wordpress.
but i cant select i correcly dont.

i had already var dumped the $order an tried various ways but  have no logic to select the object and his value / keys.
have anyone have a idea.
looping the order and meta data works but its a custom data from external plugin so i thought best choice to select the variable directly from var dump to grab the correct value.

```
   $item_data['product_id']
```

its normal way but for timezone

i tried to get

```
    $item_data['timezone']
```

its not enough i need the object before. but how?

```
object(Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order)#15792 (15) {
  ["refunded_line_items":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["status_transition":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(28) {
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "on-hold"
    ["currency"]=>
      ["version"]=>
    string(5) "5.2.2"
    ["prices_include_tax"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date_created"]=>
    object(WC_DateTime)#15785 (4) {
      ["utc_offset":protected]=>
      int(0)
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2021-04-27 10:48:01.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// Get $order object from order ID

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

Then please follow this article where explain everything how to get the value of each field.

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/